# Can you classify the data that the sensor receives in real time?

Tags: classification, sensors, iot, dpi, traffic

Can you classify the data that the sensor receives in real time?

For example, I would like to apply technologies such as DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) and Port based IP traffic classification.

Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of sensor do you mean? How is this related to Internet Protocol? Much more task details are needed to deduce something.

Comment: For example, data measured by an iot device.
What information do you need?

Comment: If your sensor generates IP packets from its measurements, these packets can be filtered/classified based on their content by some kind of DPI technology, of course. If this is the "correct" answer - ok. If you need more detailed advice, I think you should provide more details in your question to get some thoughts or experience from anyone. Because now the question seems too generic. Naturally, some DPI algorithm (and this is very "broad" notion) may be built to classify somehow any kind of IP packets, a sensor as a packet source does not contradict anything... so what?..